# Jsoup : SelectorParseException when colon in xml tag

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jsoup

Exception is thrown when xml tag has colon,

**Exception:**

org.jsoup.select.Selector$SelectorParseException: Could not parse query 'w:r': unexpected token at ':r'

**XML:**

```
<w:r>
 <w:rPr>
   <w:rStyle w:val="jid"/>
 </w:rPr>
 <w:t>AN</w:t>
</w:r>
```

**Java code:**

```
    org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.parse(documentXmlString);
```

Here documentXmlString has the xml specified above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used,

```
 documentXmlString = documentXmlString.replaceAll("w:","w");
```

Comment: good work! Upvoted !! It indeed was problem with source XML. Please refer my answer and let me know if you have any question or concerns..

Answer (score 27):

Just replace ":" with "|"

```
doc.select("w|r");
```

I'm using Jsoup 1.5.2.

Comment: If the content has ":", Then this can not work. example: http://www.google.com. If you replace it, it becomes http|//www.google.com

Answer (score 2):

Though your patchwork has worked for you.. I would like to give knowledge on namespace !

the `w:` in your XML is actually called namespace prefix. And to use neamespace prefix it has to be declared in the root node! <sup>1+</sup>
 Since the declaration part was missing in your source XML! parser was throwing an error!
Below is the way to define namespace in XML! I have corrected your own XML, I bet it wouldn't error-out now!

```
<w:r xmlns:w="http://www.w3.org/SomeNamespace">
  <w:rPr>
    <w:rStyle w:val="jid"/>
  </w:rPr>
  <w:t>AN</w:t>
</w:r>
```

**Additional information:**

The namespace has its own scope! in the below example:

```
<root>
    <w:r xmlns:w="http://www.w3.org/SomeNamespace">
      <w:rPr>
        <w:rStyle w:val="jid"/>
      </w:rPr>
      <w:t>AN</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <someotherElement>
      <dummychild/>
    </someotherElement>
```

In the above example, you cannot use namespace prefix on `<someotherElement>` or `<dummychild/>`!! because the scope of namespace prefix w is upto element `<r>` and its child (grandchild) only!

<sup>1+:The Element under which Namespace is declared.. the namespace will be valid for itself and its child nodes.. Declaring namespace under root makes namespace valid/available for all the elements in XML Document.</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot aravind. But i cannot change my input xml file with the namesapce. However the information is useful.

Comment: @Kate, I guessed that! Well. Glad you found it useful :)

Answer (score -1):

JSoup is a html not an XML parser. For XML you can use JAXB or SAXON or Xstream.

Comment: Oh thanks :) I didn't know that, so it could be a bug in it, or simple xml parser is too simple :)